# How to prove $G_2$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying abstract algebra and in one of my previous midterms there was a question that I can not solve. Now I have final exam tomorrow and want to learn the answer to that question. Here it is:

[image]

Can anyone help me with the solution of this question? My answer is there, but it would be very nice if you assume there is no answer and explain the answer to the question for part (i) and (ii), I really want to understand it. Thank you in advance

Comment: I've taken the liberty to make the image more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** (i) $(g_1,g_2)(e,g)(g_1,g_2)^{-1}=(g_1,g_2)(e,g)(g_1^{-1},g_2^{-1})=(g_1eg_1^{-1},g_2gg_2^{-1})$ $=$ $(e,g_2gg_2^{-1})$ $\in$ $\{e\}\times G_2$ for any $g_1\in G_1$ and $g,g_2\in G_2$.

(ii) Define $\varphi:G_1\times G_2\to G_1$ by $\varphi(g_1,g_2)=g_1$. Note that $\varphi$ is a surjective group homomorphism, $\ker\varphi=\{e\}\times G_2$ and apply the fundamental theorem of isomorphism for groups.

Answer (score 7):

Look at $\varphi : G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow G_1, (g,h) \mapsto g$. Why is this a homomorphism? What is its kernel?

This is enough because the normal subgroups of $G_1 \times G_2$ are exactly the kernels of group homomorphisms out of $G_1 \times G_2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that any element of $G_1$ commutes with any element of $G_2$.